# Display a debug coordinate system with libGDX OR box2D

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm currently coding a small 2D-Game using Java in Eclipse and libGDX with Box2D.
For debug reasons I would like to render a coordinate system thats visible during debugging and I have no Idea how to implement that.
The system should either be generated in libGDX showing the libGDX-Coordinates (pixels). It might also be implemented as a box2D-Object displaying the box2D-Coordinates (Pixels/PixelsPerMeter).

Is there anything builtin that I can use?

I should mention, that my map is not a classical sidescroller. The game is more or less a space-simulation with a Player moving around beeing attracted by nearby Planets (circles). The player can move freely in all directions and the camera follows him, keeping the player in exact middle of the screen. The camera also rotates with the body when it rotates.
All the rotation is the reason why I would like a coordinate system that shows me what the original X- and Y-Directions are.

Thanks for helping out, I would also be interested in a solution that manually implements a coordinate system, libGDX/Box2D don't provide anything.

UPDATE:
It seems like I was a little unclear. I do know how to get the coordinates of my elements, I would just like to visually see a coordinate system when running the game to have some orientation.
I created this poor [sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/776Bc.png), hope that makes it clear:)

Comment: "Coordinate System" is very vague, please explain what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, the key point from your downvoter is that you don't need a new coordinate system, but that you need to know the original coordinates that are independent of the camera position, since the camera moves around. The way you worded the question was confusing.

One way I would do it simply is to detect when an actor is pressed, then system.out.print() the coordinates. This is a quick and dirty trick for small things. Of course, to be easy that would mean you need a way to easily detect actor presses, this solution just assumes you already have some sort of system in place for that already.

If the purpose is for debugging specific problems, you should look into using breakpoints with your IDE. Grab an InputProcessor instance and detect some key press, then put a breakpoint. Now in debug runtime, you can press the debug key at any time to freeze the program and inspect the current state. Then you can head over to your entity and poll their x/y coordinates using the expressions window or by hovering your mouse over the variables if it's in the same class.

One professional way for generalised debugging that is used in the industry (like Skyrim) combines the first approach of clicking the actor to produce an entity ID, then being able to poll and manipulate the entity through the in game console. So one way to implement that would be, clicking an actor while the console is open prints its hashcode to the console, then you could make a method like getPosition([hashcode]) which would print out the position of the entity with the matching hashcode. There is a libGDX library for an ingame console here by StrongJoshua https://github.com/Draika/libgdx-inGameConsole

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer, but I think you got wrong what I'm trying to do. I updated my question with a sketch, what I'm looking for is basically a graphical object that displays a coordinatesystem as background in my world.
Now there I think about it, a background picture would do the job, but it would be hard to scale to the game coordinates. So an object from libGDX or something else would be nice.